# Definition of order of magnitude (Big Oh)

Tags: asymptotics

In control theory, the order of magnitude notation $\mathcal{O}(\varepsilon)$ is usually defined as:

- $f(\varepsilon)=\mathcal{O}(g(\varepsilon))$ if there exist positive constants $k$ and $c$ such that $|f(\varepsilon)|\leq k|g(\varepsilon)|$, $~\forall~ |\varepsilon|<c$.

I was wondering if the above definition is equivalent to

- $f(\varepsilon)=\mathcal{O}(g(\varepsilon))$ if $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\sup \left| \frac{f(\varepsilon)}{g(\varepsilon}\right|<\infty.$$

If they are equivalent, can you give me some references that shows this?

It seems to me that the above definitions are equivalent. I checked several examples for which both definitions worked. For instance, for $f(\varepsilon)=\frac{\varepsilon^2}{1+\varepsilon}$ we obtain $f(\varepsilon)=\mathcal O(\varepsilon^2)$ as from the first definition 
$$\left|\frac{\varepsilon^2}{1+\varepsilon}\right| < \left|\frac{1}{1-a}\right|\varepsilon^2, \quad \forall~ |\varepsilon|<a<1$$
and from the second definition we have 
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0} \frac{\frac{\varepsilon^2}{1+\varepsilon}}{\varepsilon^2}=1<\infty.$$
We could similarly show that $g(\varepsilon)=\mathcal O(\varepsilon)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they're equivalent. I can't find a standard reference for this fact, but see Theorem 2.3 in the linked course notes

https://courses.marlboro.edu/pluginfile.php/34433/mod_page/content/1/week6.pdf

as well as the several related MSE questions

- [About the limsup definition of big-O](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291703/about-the-limsup-definition-of-big-o)
- [O-Notation: Understanding Limsup Definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2000451/o-notation-understanding-limsup-definition)